# Set id on Runnable

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How can I set id on Runnable in this code

```
Runnable rd = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        populatePanel(referList.get(handler.getPosition()), handler.getPosition());
        if (i == referList.size() - 1) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(rd, delay);
```

l want to distinguish one thread from other

Comment: Are you sure this is about "multithreading" - isn't this just a runnable that is post to some event queue? The thread will probably be the same for all runnables...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set the name on the thread, not on the Runnable, for example using the following:

```
    RunnableJob runnableJob = new RunnableJob();

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(runnableJob);
    thread1.setName("thread1");
    thread1.start();

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnableJob, "thread2");
    thread2.start();

    Thread thread3 = new Thread(runnableJob);
    thread3.start();

    Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println("Main thread: " + currentThread.getName() + "(" +currentThread.getId() + ")");
```

This will print the following:

```
RunnableJob is being run by thread1 (11)
RunnableJob is being run by thread2 (12)
Main thread: main(1)
RunnableJob is being run by Thread-1 (13)
```

Source [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-identify-a-thread.html).

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to distinguish threads is the give a name to each thread. See ThreadFactory for the ExecutorService in java.util.concurrent package.

Alternatively, if you really have a business case that you want to distinguish through runnable, you need to implement your own class and refer to some member variables.

To me, ThreadFactory with ExecutorService is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an anonymous subclass. In terms of subclassing, there is nothing special here, i.e. you can easily add an `private final int ID = 42` field to your class, and then make use of that field inside your run method or in the `toString` method, for example. If you need to add public API, you cannot use an anonymous class, though, but you could use an inner class instead that implements another interface.

Answer (score 0):

Create inner class with instance id.

```
handler.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(1), delay);  
handler.postDelayed(new MyRunnable(2), delay);




class MyRunnable implements Runnable{    
  long id;  
  public MyRunnable(long id){  
this.id = id;  
}
  @Override  
    public void run() {  
        populatePanel(referList.get(handler.getPosition()), handler.getPosition());  
        if (i == referList.size() - 1) {  
            i = 0;  
        }  
    }

}
```